How to make a real time countdown in Bash while taking user input
i want to take user input and make a real time countdown like the following:

readFile(){
    linenumber=1
    end=10
    while  [ $linenumber -lt 18 ];do
        for (( i=0; i<=10; i++ )); do
            echo -ne "Time Remaining: $(expr $end - $i)\033[0K\r"
            sleep 1
            sed -n "$linenumber, $((linenumber + 5))p" < QuestionBank.txt            
            echo
            echo
            echo -n "Please Choose an Asnwer: "
            read -t 1 -n 1 answer
            echo
        done
        linenumber=$((linenumber + 6))
    done
}

here is my code
I expected it to work like in the picture above, but every second that passes, it prints the whole output again.

I am not sure it would be easy to do that in bash. Bash is not really good for waiting on input and modify the terminal at the same time. It could probably be done using tput but the result would likely be very buggy.

If you wish to clear the screen and (re)print from the first line in the console you can use clear:
$ cat timer.clear
#!/bin/bash

unset answer
timer=5

while ((timer > 0))
do
    clear                                     # clear console and reset to first line

    echo "Time Remaining: ${timer} seconds"
    echo ""
    cat QuestionBank.txt
    echo ""

    read -t1 -n1 -p "Choose your option: " answer && break

    (( timer-- ))
done

echo ""
echo "############"
typeset -p answer

Taking for a test drive:

first invocation times out after 5 seconds
second invocation exits the loop after selecting 'b'
notice each pass through the loop clears the entire console and starts over from line 1


If you don't want to clear the entire console for each pass through the loop there are an assortment of ways to do this with tput.  One idea:
$ cat timer.tput
#!/bin/bash

unset answer
timer=5

tput sc                                       # save current cursor location in console

while ((timer > 0))
do
    tput rc                                   # move cursor to save point created by "tput sc"
    tput ed                                   # clear everything from here 'down' to end of console

    echo "Time Remaining: ${timer} Seconds"
    echo ""
    cat QuestionBank.txt
    echo ""

    read -t1 -n1 -p "Choose your option: " answer && break

    (( timer-- ))
done

echo ""
echo "############"
typeset -p answer

Taking for a test drive:

first invocation times out after 5 seconds
second invocation exits the loop after selecting 'b'
notice on each pass through the loop we reset back to where the current invocation started; everything displayed in the console prior to the current invocation is still visible



You're looking for something like this:
tput smcup
trap 'tput rmcup' EXIT
while question=$(head -n 6 <&3); [[ $question ]]; do
  for ((t = 10; t >= 0; t--)); do
    tput clear
    echo Time remaining: $t seconds
    echo
    echo "$question"
    echo
    read -p 'Your answer: ' -t 1 -n 1 answer && break
  done
  # TODO check $t and do something with $answer
done 3<QuestionBank.txt

